# GPU chip with a film around the core

Tags: laptop, gpu, thermal-paste

I want to apply thermal grease on my laptop GPU, but I've noticed there is a film sticked to the GPU chipset around the core. Personally I think it's an antistatic film, because it is covering those small resistors around. But I am not sure about it. Can anyone explain what is it for? And can I remove it at all? Because it seems some old thermal grease got under it and I want to unstick it at all.

Comment: The laptop make and model would help then it can easily be researched.

Comment: Benq R56 it has GF 8400 GS based on the G98 (D8M) chip. I don't think  film is laptop specific.

Comment: Generally speaking, I've never seen a film on any die for anything, on that matter I would take the film off and put the paste on as necessary.

Comment: Any chance of a photo?

Comment: Definitely. When I'll receive my ordered thermal paste I am going to disassemble it, make some photos and update this question/thread.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the film is to aid automatic thermal paste application. Basically machines will apply thermal paste to an area and the film is there to make sure that the that area mostly covers the GPU itself and doesn't contaminate those SMD components you're seeing.

You can freely remove it because it doesn't do anything at this point and applying thermal paste by hand (if you know how to do it) is much more precise and the chance that thermal paste will leak everywhere is lower.